# How to find pairs of a card pack list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

I have the following list in python.

```
list = ['10♠', '10♣', '2♡', '4♠', '4♣', '5♡', '5♣', '6♡', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'K♠', 'K♢', 'Q♡']
```

how can I remove pairs from this? As an example, if a number appears an odd number of times, the last appearance of it should be kept. All others should be removed. Including all the ones that appear an even number of times.

ex: From `'9♡'`, `'9♢'`, `'9♣'`, only the `'9♣'` should be kept.

Can someone help me with this?

I tried to use the below code to identify indices first. But still no luck.

```
i = 0
        while i < len(deck): 
            count = 0
            k = len(deck[i])
            pivot = i
            j = i
            while j < len(deck): 
                if deck[i][:k-1] == deck[j][:k-1]:
                    print(deck[i]+','+deck[j])
                    count+= 1 
                    pivot = j
                j+=1
            if (count %2 != 0): 
                print('pivot:'+str(pivot))
            i = pivot +1
            i +=1
```

No need to consider symbols. Just want to remove pairs from the list.

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Is the order significant?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I was about to ask the same question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from collections import defaultdict
deck = ['10♠', '10♣', '2♡', '4♠', '4♣', '5♡', '5♣', '6♡', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'K♠', 'K♢', 'Q♡']

# Create a dictionary and group all the cards with same number
groups = defaultdict(list)
for card in deck:
    key = card[:-1]
    groups[key].append(card)

new_deck = []
for subgroup in groups.values():
    # iterate through the dictionary
    # If you have odd number of cards in a subgroup
    # consider the last card in that subgroup
    if len(subgroup)%2 == 1:
        new_deck.append(subgroup[-1])

for card in new_deck:
    print(card)
```

Output

```
2♡ 8♣ 9♣ A♣ J♢ Q♡
```

**Edit:** A minor simplification to the second iteration with `groups.values`, thanks to RoadRunner.

Comment: @RoadRunner You are right about the `.values`! I just saw that we basically have the same idea :) This feels like a natural way to go about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Group the card pairs into a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then only return the last card from uneven pairs in a new list using a list comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ['10♠', '10♣', '2♡', '4♠', '4♣', '5♡', '5♣', '6♡', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'K♠', 'K♢', 'Q♡']

cards = defaultdict(list)
for card in lst:
    cards[card[:-1]].append(card)

result = [pairs[-1] for pairs in cards.values() if len(pairs) % 2]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['2♡', '8♣', '9♣', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'Q♡']
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the same order, you can use:

```
import re

l = ['10♠', '10♣', '2♡', '4♠', '4♣', '5♡', '5♣', '6♡', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'K♠', 'K♢', 'Q♡']

nc, nl = [], [0]

for x in l:
    clean = re.sub(r"[^A-Z\d]", "", x)
    if clean != nl[-1]:
        nl.append(clean)
        nc.append(x)
    else:
        del nl[-1]
        del nc[-1]

print(nc)
# ['2♡', '8♣', '9♣', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'Q♡']
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/24f8878c5c)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `list` is a reserved keyword, you should never name your variables after reserved keywords, use `lst` instead of `list`

Now, Here is the minimal solution:

```
lst = ['10♠', '10♣', '2♡', '4♠', '4♣', '5♡', '5♣', '6♡', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♢', 'K♠', 'K♢', 'Q♡']
dictionary = dict.fromkeys(list('A23456789JQK')+['10'])   

for item in lst: 
    dictionary[item[:-1]] = item if dictionary[item[:-1]] is None else None                                                                                    

print(list(filter(None.__ne__, dictionary.values())))
```

output:

```
['A♣', '2♡', '8♣', '9♣', 'J♢', 'Q♡']
```